# SqlDataAdapter Get Identity

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I'm doing the following to get the identity of an inserted row:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnetion("connectiontxc");
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Student");

void adap_RowUpdated(object sender, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        e.Row["Id"] = (new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select @@Identity")).ExecuteScalar();          
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the identity automatically?